# Images rendering on HTML canvas in poor quality on smaller screen size

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas

i made a website - clone of million dollar homepage.
But i have a major problem.
Images rendered on canvas on big screens appear normal (good quality).
Here's the picture:
[image]

But when i open the webiste on my phone, all pictures are barely visible. See here:
[image]
and here is a closer look
[image]

the images are drawn on canvas by this function

```
  context.drawImage(img, myOptions.x, myOptions.y, myOptions.sw, myOptions.sh)
```

do you have any solution how to fix this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ahoj! Try to check if there isn't some special resolution for smaller screens, or maybe change resolution od that canvas. Because on desktop you can see normally some picture but on smaller resolution canvas can crop or edit pictures to fit into to the screen